# Multiple Shared Elements

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have the following situation inside of a soccer application.
We want to implement the shared elements between all these activities.

[image: Shared Elements Situation]

In my viewholder on the first `Activity` for the match I have set a `android:transitionName` which corresponds to the same transitionName on the second `Activity`.

```
<!-- item_viewholder (first activity) -->
<CustomViewContainingImageViewAndTextView
     android:id="@+id/item_match_hometeam"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:transitionName="@string/transition_morph_match_header_homeTeam" />

<!-- header (second activity) -->
<CustomViewContainingImageViewAndTextView
     android:id="@+id/item_match_hometeam_header"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:transitionName="@string/transition_morph_match_header_homeTeam" />
```

I start the second `Activity` with

```
final String awayTeamTransition = activityContext.getString(R.string.transition_morph_match_header_awayTeam);
final String homeTeamTransition = activityContext.getString(R.string.transition_morph_match_header_homeTeam);
final ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                   activityContext,
                   Pair.create(homeTeam, homeTeamTransition),
                   Pair.create(awayTeam, awayTeamTransition));
activityContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Now this transition works fine but what if I want to have an even deeper detail.
Displaying statistics about the selected team and I want to have shared transition there too?

I tried setting the `transitionName` programmatically when the `CustomViewContainingImageViewAndTextView` was clicked to the new `transitionName`.

```
final String teamViewTransition = activityContext.getString(R.string.transition_morph_teamview_to_detail);
//teamView is the view that was clicked.
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(teamView, teamViewTransition);

final ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
     activityContext,
     Pair.create(teamView, teamViewTransition));
activityContext.startActivity(teamInfoActivityIntent, options.toBundle());
```

this transitionName corresponds to the `ImageView` on the third `Activity`

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/team_info_header_logo"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:transitionName="@string/transition_morph_teamview_to_detail" />
```

However the enterTransition fails, but the exitTransition works!
However this breaks the exitTransition from 2 --> 1

Sight.
Hope someone takes some time to figure this out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

Beyond any doubt, the problem is because you are changing `transitionName` of the view that you want to share from second `Activity` to third. But you should simply keep that `transitionName` in the second `Activity` but change `transitionName` of the view in **third** `Activity`'s `onCreate` method, according to what we want to share from second `Activity`.

So let's keep our transition from first `Activity` to second, as it's working as expected. Let's look at the second `Activity`: we just need to send the `transitionName` of view, that we want to share **as an extra of `Intent`** to third `Activity` and then assign this value **programmatically** to the shared view in third `Activity`.

So here is the code of our **second** `Activity`:

```
View homeTeam = findViewById(R.id.home_team_detail);
View awayTeam = findViewById(R.id.away_team_detail);

View.OnClickListener onTeamClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Activity activityContext = MultipleElementsDetail.this;
        final ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                activityContext,
                Pair.create(v, v.getTransitionName()));
        startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, SingleElementDetail.class)
           .putExtra("shared_element_transition_name", v.getTransitionName()), options.toBundle());
    }
};

homeTeam.setOnClickListener(onTeamClickListener);
awayTeam.setOnClickListener(onTeamClickListener);
```

So what I did here is just created the same `OnClickListener` for both teams, which creates shared transition, and starts new activity with `Intent` having `transitionName` of shared view as an extra.

And then in **third** `Activity` I've just get this extra from `Intent` and set it as a `transitionName` of shared view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_element_detail);

    View team = findViewById(R.id.team_single);

    String transitionName = getIntent().getStringExtra("shared_element_transition_name");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(transitionName)) {
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(team, transitionName);
    }
}
```

And as a result we have something like this (I've used explode transition to better see the difference between activities):

[image]

Hope that helps and exactly the same what you want! :)

Comment: Hey man! I like your solution however my imageView in my third activity is in an fragment and in a recyclerview. So I would have to give my transition name to my activity pass it to my fragment pass it to my adapter pass it to my viewholder. What a hassle...

Comment: Yep, or you can save it in `SharedPreferences` or in database and then extract it in your `ViewHolder`/`Adapter`. Or you can set it as a `static` variable somewhere. Or you can even set it as a field in your model (i.e. `Team` class, it would be the simpliest way) and again then extract in `onBindViewHolder`. Anyway, you need to set it in runtime, cause you don't know what would be shared until it would be clicked :)

Comment: Could you post the code for this? I somehow just couldn't reproduce what you presented.

Answer (score 8):

I had this doubt myself, but I feel like the answer above is a little bit confusing. To put it simply if you have more than one shared elements to animate, you can create "Pair" of View & transitionName as much as you want. Here is a sample code for this:

```
    Pair statusAnim = Pair.create(holder.getOrderStatusView(), "track_job_status");
    Pair driverBundleAnim = Pair.create(holder.getDriverProfileBundle(), "driver_profile_bundle");
    ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, statusAnim, driverBundleAnim);
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, TrackingActivity.class), transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```