# activity just blinking after using shared element transition

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation, android-transitions

Hi i am developing an app where i'm using shared element transition to animate enter and exit transitions on login and register activity animating one imageview and two textviews but my problem is that views are not animated at all instead when i click on register button the register activity blinks twice and no animation occurs and moreover the image in register activity losses its shape so i dont know where i'm going wrong becaues i have given same transition names in both the activites still the problem exists so i would appreciate some help.
Here is my styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>

        <!-- Transition -->
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="21">@android:transition/fade
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition" tools:targetApi="21">@android:transition/fade
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="21">
            @android:transition/move
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition" tools:targetApi="21">
            @android:transition/move
        </item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

my login activity

```
public void gotoregister(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
        Pair[] pairs  = new Pair[3];
        pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String>(text_login,getResources().getString(R.string.login_text_transition));
        pairs[1] = new Pair<View,String>(login_page_curve,getResources().getString(R.string.transition_name_signup));
        pairs[2] = new Pair<View,String>(register_text,getResources().getString(R.string.register_text_transition));
        ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
                (LoginActivity.this,pairs);
        startActivity(intent,optionsCompat.toBundle());
        finish();
        //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottom_up,R.anim.bottom_down);

    }
```

Comment: add `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` in style i hope it will help you.

Comment: @Hardik tried using your solution still not working

Comment: try below code.

Comment: if you set hardwareAccelerated=false in your application or actual activity tag your animation transactions will be avoided

Answer (score 1):

This is working in my code.

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    s<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarMain">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml(v21)

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: when i make new project with simple layout transition works but with complex layout it doesnt work at all that is why i'm confused..

Comment: @john  if this line is present in `manifest.xml` file `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` remove this line from application tag.

Comment: did thatstill no use.

Comment: i have a layerlist which losses its shape while animating what could be the reason..

Comment: and the second issue is that now my custom layerlist is losing its shape aftergiving transition name

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
View sharedView = splashLogo;
            String transitionName = getString(R.string.splash_logo_animate);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashscreenActivity.this, sharedView, transitionName);
                startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
                finishAfterTransition();
            }
            else {
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashscreenActivity.this, sharedView, transitionName);
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(getApplicationContext(), i, options.toBundle());
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: nope still the same.. but thanks for your time and patience

Comment: but can you help me the layer list it is actually losing its shape while trying to animate

Comment: [refer this one hope it will help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491282/multiple-shared-elements)

Comment: No actually i wanted to ask you about the layerlist which has custom shape but the custom shape losses its width in second activity

Comment: @john [please check this one](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Animation.md)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170619/discussion-between-hardik-vasani-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using these in your style theme?

```
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you finish the current activity after start new one with transition. The enter and exit transition is lost if you finish that way.

Try to keep the `LoginActivity` to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

For smooth transition, follow these two steps.
Create image_transform.xml file in res/transition folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet>
  <changeImageTransform />
  <changeBounds />
  <changeClipBounds />
  <changeTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

Write these 2 lines in your called activity after findViewById(android.R.id.content).setTransitionName("userPic");

```
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.image_transform));
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.image_transform));
```